# How to send Optional parameters from angular and catch them in Java Controller?

Tags: java, angularjs

I'm trying to send "search" parameters to Spring Controller but keep getting the 400 bad request . I tried `@RequestParam("personalNumber")String personalNumber` but it still doesn't work, so now I'm trying to get the wrapper , can you suggest how to send wrapper info to Java controller ? (Wrapper has instances of other classes)

### AngularJs

```
angular.extend($scope, {
    obj:{
        personalNumber:"",
        firstName:"",
        lastName:"",
        dateFrom:"",
        dateTo:""
    },

    loadCarLoan: urls.BASE_API + "user/getOnlineApplicationList",
    carLoanList:[

    ],

});


$scope.getCarLoan =  function () {
    $(".loader").show();
    console.log("In the angular");
    $http.post($scope.loadCarLoan + $.param($scope.obj))
      .success(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        if(response.success){
            $scope.carLoanList = response;
        }
        $(".loader").hide();
    }).error(function () {
        $(".loader").hide();
        $scope.carLoanList = [];
    })
};

$scope.filter = function () {
    $scope.getCarLoan();
};
```

### Java Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "user/getOnlineApplicationList", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String getOnlineApplicationList(HttpSession session,
                                                     @RequestBody OnlineApplicationListWrapper wrapper) {

    System.out.println("In the Controller Java");

    HashMap<String, Object> jsonMap = new HashMap<>();

    Car car = wrapper.getCar();
    Loan loan = wrapper.getLoan();
    CustPaymentPlan cpp = wrapper.getCpp();
    NaturalPerson np = wrapper.getPerson();

    jsonMap.put("success", "true");
    jsonMap.put("car", car);
    jsonMap.put("loan", loan);
    jsonMap.put("cpp", cpp);
    jsonMap.put("np", np);

    System.out.println(wrapper.getCar().toString());
    System.out.println(wrapper.getLoan().toString());
    System.out.println(wrapper.getCpp().toString());
    System.out.println(wrapper.getPerson().toString());
    System.out.println("========");
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(jsonMap));

    return gson.toJson(jsonMap);

}
```

Comment: what is your api? you send to server

Comment: Look at the request in the Network tab of the Developer Console. You should see that the URL of the POST is malformed. It needs a question mark (`"?"`) between the path and the search parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

```
@RequestParam("personalNumber") String personalNumber
```

To:

```
@RequestParam(value = "personalNumber", required = false) String personalNumber
```

The `required = false` indicates to spring that the parameter can be optional.

No need to create a wrapper